# How to load children from Firebase

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some code that will store the number of times a particular OS has been voted for on Firebase. I use the following to store it:

```
DatabaseReference windowsChoice;
```

And inside the onCreate method:

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Windows");
```

Inside the button method I store the data to firebase with:

```
String id = "TimesClicked";
windowsChoice.child(id).setValue(b); //b holds the amount of times that Windows has been clicked
```

The resulting format is such:

```
{"Windows":{"TimesClicked":8},"choice1Num":23} // ignore choice1Num
```

The following code will get me the value of Windows (TimesClicked:8):

```
String result = new Connector().execute().get();
JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(result);
String jsonString = ob.getString("Windows");

String id = "TimesClicked";
windowsChoice.child(id).setValue(b); 

intent.putExtra("result", jsonString);
startActivity(intent);
```

But how can I get the value of the TimesClicked label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how can I get the value of the TimesClicked label?

Simply, by using the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference timesClickedRef = rootRef.child("Windows").child("TimesClicked");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long timesClicked = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
        Log.d("TAG", "timesClicked: " + timesClicked);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
timesClickedRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
timesClicked: 8
```

Comment: How can I access the timesClicked outside of the OnDataChange if its declared inside the method?

Comment: You can only use it there or you can pass it to another method. This is because Firebase APIs are asynchronous. There is a workaround for that, in which you can use a [custom callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774).